# BroadcastReceiver not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am writing an android app that silences and unsilences a phone when certain time is reached, on a weekly basis. However, the broadcastreceiver only fires once when I compile the code. Anyone know why? It does not fire at all after that. I have heard of the CWAC WakefulIntent, but I am designing for API 4 and hence cannot use it.

Listed below are my 2 broadcast receivers and Alarm class which sets the alarm. Silent for silencing the phone and Normal for unsilencing the phone.

Silent.java: http://pasteit.com/381
Normal.java: http://pasteit.com/380
Alarm.java: ""/382

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of this problem is that you are not declaring the Broadcast Receivers in your manifest.

Comment: I did declare the 2 receivers in the manifest.  <receiver android:name=".Silent"/>
     
     <receiver android:name=".Normal"/>

Comment: You will probably need to add `<intent-filter>`s which match your alarm `PendingIntent`s to each of those receiver declarations. Also, you may need to specify custom Actions on the `Intents` that you are creating for your `PendingIntents` and use those custom Actions in your `<intent-filter>` specifications.

Comment: Oh, what are the steps in declaring an intent filter? Also, is it possible that my broadcastreceivers may be terminated prematurely as receivers have a time constraint?

Comment: Well, googling "android BroadcastReceiver example" finds a good tutorial on BroadcastReceivers & Intent Filters:  http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/

Comment: I have added intent filters but the receivers still do not activate.

Comment: Do the Intents that you're adding to the `PendingIntent`s now match the intent filters?

Comment: Yes, I cloned the intents in a loop to vary the extras but the filters should be the same.

Comment: I really can't advise any further without seeing your current code.

Comment: I dun mind sending u the code but it is kinda long. Which part do you want or would you prefer the whole project?

Comment: I need to see your updated `Alarm.java` and your manifest to check that the changes that you have made to your `Intent`/`PendingIntent` objects matches the `<receiver>` declarations in your manifest.

Comment: You shouldn't be using explicit intents here (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires for a description of explicit / implicit intents). They will only resolve with internal calls inside your app, and your Receiver is being called externally from the Alarm. Also, I don't understand why you are cloning Intents. Simply construct an intent: `Intent myIntent = new Intent( "super.ivle.boy.silent" );` and add this to your `PendingIntent`.

Comment: As an aside, I think that your scheduling of alarms is **very** inefficient. Rather than setting lots of alarms, why now work out when the next alarm is due, and just set one. When that alarm triggers, then you can schedule the next one. If the user changes anything which changes your alarm schedule, then cancel the existing one and re-schedule it.

Comment: I am cloning intents to prevent placing different extras into the same intent throughout the loop.

Comment: Try just constructing a new intent and adding your extras. Cloning still has to create a new object, so is no more efficient that constructing a new one. The key thing is to use he correct constructor so that you are creating an implicit Intent rather than an explicit one.

Comment: I changed to using implicit intents but there's no difference.

Comment: Without access to your Adapter, I cannot debug this for you. Are you sure that you are setting the Alarms? Why not try replacing your current `Alarm( Context context )` constructor (which is fairly complex) with a simple one which sets a single alarm through AlarmManager without using your Adapter? That will enable you to separate issues with your alarms / receivers with issues with iterating your data. I would strongly re-iterate that you would be better to set a single alarm for the next scheduled event than set potentially hundreds (as your current code will).

Comment: Thanks a lot of your help. I will try to change to utilise a single alarm and see how it goes.